# Grape Entity expose to delegate/forward to other object

Tags: ruby-grape, grape-entity

When using Grape Entity, sometimes we want to expose a few fields from an inner/related object. We can simply do this by:

```
expose(:bar) { |entity| entity.foo.bar }
```

However if many fields needs this treatment, this can get very repetitive. Is there a way to define delegation / forward so a bunch of `expose` all are associated with another object?

Answer (score 0):

create a separate entity for `foo` class, let's call it `API::Entities::Foo`. then you can

```
  expose :foo, using: API::Entities::Foo
```

you have to follow REST guidelines to serialize like this. you are dealing with [resources](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level1). don't break it to flat, cumbersome data structures.